# Printer sharing using Fedora

Tags: fedora, printing, lxde

I have to PC and netbook runs on fedora

- PC - Fedora 21 (Workstation)
- Netbook - Fedora LXDE

Both of these computers are connected to the same network (PC wired and netbook wireless)

My HP Deskjet 1010 printer is connected to the PC via a USB cable.

I want to enable printing over network for my netbook.

Comment: There is no "add printer" option on LXDE version of Fedora 21.

Comment: Do you have `system-config-printer`?

Comment: I'm sorry i have no idea what "system-config-printer" (I'm new to Linux)

Comment: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/02/cups-admin-ui-access/

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu/Linux Mint, all I have to do is go to 'Settings-printer-add a printer-find network printer'. After a few seconds, it shows my printer on the list. Fedora should have something fairly similar.

Comment: Well on Fedora GNOME there is. but not in the LXDE version.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry for the advice then. Its been a while since I used and LXDE desktop environment. I am going to ask a really stupid question, but is there a settings menu, and if so, is there a printer option at all?

Comment: well, it has a menu. but there is no printer option 
"noting related to printing" as far as I know.

Comment: I did some research. Try system->administration->printing

Comment: There is no such option I'm afraid.

Comment: Try going back to your settings menu, and see if there is an 'administration' option. If there is go into it and see what's in it. If that doesn't work, open up your terminal and type in 'system-config-printer' and see what comes up.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I'm afraid, in the administration sub menu the only 2 remianing options are "Firewall" and "Yum Extender"

Comment: I was looking at some Fedora LXDE screenshots. When you click the F (the fedora icon) on the bottom left corner, there should (in addition to other things) a 'prefrence'  and an 'administration' option. Do you happen to have those two options on yours? Or was it the same administration option you were looking in? Fedora.com said that their printing configure tool was in some administration option somewhere. Also, when you hooked up your other printer, did you just have hook it up and it worked, or did you have to go somewhere on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

if there is no system configuration for printer then install it in terminal
`dnf install system-config-printer.x86_64`

or you can logged off your LXDE, logged into gnome (session). Went to "show applications", selected "all", clicked "utilities", then "settings", then "printers", then "unlock" and
simply add your printer